# How do I make Windows launch a new instance of explorer.exe when I open My Computer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do I make Windows launch a new instance of explorer.exe when I open My Computer?  I know there is a setting that does this.  I turned it on previously, and the performance increase was noticeable.

Comment: Stackoverflow really isn't intended as a place for general, non-programming computer questions like this.

Comment: As Chris said, this is not a programming question. Closed.

Answer (score 14):

It's under tools in any explorer window

Tools->Folder Options->View->Launch Folder Windows in new Process

Answer (score 0):

Tools, Folder Options... then something about "Launch each folder in a separate process" or similar, in a long list of checkboxes.

Don't have Windows at hand, so I can't look it up in more detail :)

Comment: Yep. It's "open each folder in its own window" and it's only a list of two radio buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7/8 It's under Tools > Folder Options, View tab at the top.  Check off Launch folder windows in separate process.  On Windows 10 it's under File > Change folder and search options.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was:

View tab --> Options --> Change folder and search options, then select View tab, then put a check in the box next to "Launch folder windows in a separate process".